# Is there any approach in visualize speed-measure-webpack.json file?

Tags: webpack, plugins, frontend, angular-cli

Currently, I am using `speed-measure-webpack` plugin in gathering building time of all used webpack plugins, etc.

[image]

Since my project is integrated with Angular CLI, I couldn't modify setting to output speed-measure-webpack to the commands, but store it directly into a `.json` file. It's pretty hard to watch it in plain text format, is there any visualization tools to help me analyze it, such as `webpack-bundle-analyzer` for `stats.json`?